# Can I update rows in sql based on a table generated in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I apologize if this question isn't asked well - first post on here. Very new with PHP and SQL in general.

I have a table displayed using a PHP foreach loop.

query:

```
SELECT * FROM ftu_inventory WHERE issuedto='$_GET[id]' ORDER BY item ASC
```

(using id 134 as example - partid is a unique primary key auto-assigned when the line is inserted)

| partid | item | issuedto | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | Beret | 134 | On Hand |
| 16 | Boots | 134 | On Hand |
| 72 | Jacket | 134 | On Hand |
| 250 | Jacket | 134 | On Hand |
| 103 | Pants | 134 | On Hand |
| 240 | Pants | 134 | On Hand |

'Status' is displayed using a drop-down menu. I would like to have a button at the top of the badge to save all displayed rows with the new drop-down values in that column.

I know I could have a save button included in each row as part of the foreach loop, but there has to be a more effective way, no?

Comment: Please post the (HTML) form code as well. In short you could name the `select` as `<select name="status[ID_OF_THE_ROW]">` and then foreach each row in PHP

Comment: You are open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) by the way

Comment: Use `<input type="hidden">` fields and a useful structure for [nested arrays in form data](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) to submit row ids and new values in one go…

Answer (score 0):

If status will be updated to the same value, e.g. `status = "On Hand"`, then you can do:

```sql
UPDATE ftu_inventory SET status = :newStatus WHERE id IN (...)
```

---

But if each item will update to it's own status, then you can group by new status, and then do fewer updates than just iterate through all:

```php
   ...
   $statuses = array_column($items, null, 'status'); // Index by "status" array key

   foreach ($statuses as $status => $itemsBatch) {
       $this->update($status, array_column($itemsBatch, 'id'));
   }
   ...
}

public function update(string $status, array $ids): void
{
    $this->sql('UPDATE ftu_inventory SET status = :newStatus WHERE id IN :ids', [':newStatus' => $status, ':ids' => $ids]);
}
```

*Code is pseudo-code and contains lots of missing actual code*